# Neovim has wrong background setting

Tags: vimrc, neovim, colorscheme, color, background

I'm having a trouble with Neovim colors when using my `vimrc` file as Neovim's `init.vim`.

Here's the expected look, how it looks in Vim:

[image: correct look]

And here is how it looks in Neovim:

[image: wrong look]

I guess that's because of the `:set background?` shows:

```
background=dark
```

although it's obviously light and **it's set as `set background=light`** in the `init.vim` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background` setting actually doesn't control the background colors but more the foregrounds colors. It dates from a time (that includes the present for some terminal) where the background couldn't be controlled.

It is a way to tell the `colorscheme` or Vim in general what kind of color should be selected to offer a good contrast with the background (i.e. select light foreground color if the `background` is `dark`, select dark foreground color if the `background` is `light).

Remark: about the reason for which the sequence of the `background` option setting and the `colorscheme` settings is important is the following line of the `default` `colorscheme`:

```
set bg&
```

It resets the `background` option to its default which is `dark`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was that the order of options in the `init.vim` file is important.

Originally it was:

```
set background=light
colorscheme default
```

**I changed it to**

```
colorscheme default
set background=light
```

**And it started to look correctly.** Don't know if that's specified in the docs.

Comment: The `$VIMRUNTIME/colors/default.vim` as a `set bg&` that reset the `background` option to its default (which is `dark`).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt anyway it's strange that despite the color scheme sets it's to dark it remains light in practice. Not sure if it's documented or more like a bug

Comment: It is a feature :-) It dates from the time Vim couldn't control the background of the terminal. The setting only controls the foreground colors based on the indication of the terminal background (`dark` or `light`).

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt thank you, that actually qualifies for the answer to the question, would you mind post it?